# How to get transformed value of key from Web.config

Tags: c#, web-config, web.config-transform

I have the following key in my `Web.config` file:

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="ImageBucketName" value="dev" />
</appSettings>
```

I have the following transformation in my `Web.Release.Config` file:

```
<configuration xmlns:xdt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/XML-Document-Transform">
  <appSettings>
    <add key="ImageBucketName" value="live" xdt:Transform="SetAttributes" xdt:Locator="Match(key)" />
  </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

However, when I run my application from Visual Studio 2013 and attempt to retrieve the value of the key from with my controller, I am always getting the non-transformed version of the key.

```
// Get the AWS bucket name from the config file
var imageBucketName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ImageBucketName"];
```

The same result with the following:

```
// Get the AWS bucket name from the config file
var imageBucketName = WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ImageBucketName"];
```

How can I ensure that I'm getting the correct **Release** version of the key when I'm running the application as 'Release'?

Comment: What does the web.config file look like in your output folder (usually `\bin` for a web project)?

Comment: Sorry, Yes I can.  I'm having a look now

Comment: The web.config created shows the non-transformed version, thus returning 'dev'

Comment: And you have definitely set the configuration to 'Release' (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wx0123s5(v=vs.120).aspx)?

Comment: Yes.  It seems to only be transforming when I do an actual 'Deploy', not just by setting the 'Release/Debug' setting from the toolbar

Comment: Hmmm i wonder if that's the default behaviour.  Maybe I need to [do this](http://sebnilsson.com/a5410281/asp-net-transform-web-config-with-debug-release-on-build/) ?

Comment: Ah, yes, it won't work unless you deploy - transforms make sense for different environments, with the defaults for your development environment being those from the base web.config file. The '.release' transforms would be applicable to your prod (or prod-like) environments, into which you need to deploy the app. Any particular reason why you want to apply the transform while running locally?

Comment: Ahh right, well if that's just the default behaviour then that's fine.  I just wanted to see the transformation working within my environment that was all :o).  If you want to post an answer to that effect then I'd be happy to accept.  Thanks for your time

Comment: If you just want to see the transform in action, one option is to run it through the command line XDT tool: https://ctt.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Transforms won't be applied when running directly in Visual Studio - you would need to at least deploy somewhere (even if locally) first.

The rationale is something along the lines of transforms being applicable to different environments. The base web.config file represents the local (dev) environment, while the `.release` transforms would be applicable for prod (or prod-like) environments.

If you just want to see the transforms in action, an easy way to run them is via the command-line XDT tool available from https://ctt.codeplex.com/